# Python - change JSON values and pretty print

Tags: python, json, structure

How to change Values in JSON by using Python in any of the nodes (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7):

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "level2": {
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "level3": [
            {
                "key4": "value4",
                "level5": [
                    {
                        "key5": "value5",
                        "key6": "value6"
                    }
                ],
                "key7": "value7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After changing e.g. Value6 with some other value - I would like to print that new JSON in a nice print format (same as above).

Thanks.

Comment: Deserialize the json... modify the object, reserialize the json using the `indent` parameter to `json.dump`....

Comment: what did you try¿

Comment: You call that format "nice"? Despite all that inconsistent spacing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update json file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949637/how-to-update-json-file-with-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to first convert the string to a python dictionary, then manipulate the dictionary, and finally dump the dictionary back to a string. Here's a simple example:

```
import json
json_string = '{"foo": "bar"}'
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
json_dict["foo"] = "baz"
print json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4)
```

Comment: This works good and just wondering is there a way to keep order of KEYS the same as in original string? For example - sometimes I get KEY7 before KEY4 (but in correct level) when convert to dictionary and then print out with json.dumps....

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, but check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760/1739725