# Python modify structure (to be accepted by BQ) of JSON with python and save it

Tags: python, json

I would like to ask if there is an easy way to modify JSON by using Python?

I have found some of the relevant topic- [How to update json file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949637/how-to-update-json-file-with-python/13949836) But could not figure out the solution for my current issue.

Currently, JSON looks like this:

```
    {
         "X": [
           {
               "sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_1",
               ...
           }
           {
               "sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_2",
               ...
           }
           ......
         ]
         "Y": [
           {
               "sample_topic_y":"sample_content_y_1",
               ...
           }
           {
               "sample_topic_y":"sample_content_y_2",
               ...
           }
           ......
         ]
}
```

Required: To be accepted by BQ / Need to remove "Y", keep only "X" in this format.

```
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_1",.....}
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_2",.....}
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_3",.....}
```

Any relevant documentation, topics?

**P.S> Update 1.0**

```
import json
json_path = 'C:\XXX\exportReport.json'

def updateJsonFile():
jsonFile = open(json_path, "r") # Open the JSON file for reading
data = json.load(jsonFile) # Read the JSON into the buffer
jsonFile.close() # Close the JSON file

updateJsonFile()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. With loads you could read the json, do your modifications on Python dicts or lists and then write it back using dumps.

Comment: Your required format is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande This file generated by using API, and thus the output of JSON file. I need this specific format, as BigQuery accept only this way (As tested), but this could be not right as well.

Comment: `json.load` will not work in the required format.

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande What could I do make this happens?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import json
json_path = 'C:\XXX\exportReport.json'
output_path = 'C:\XXX\your_output_file.txt'

with open(json_path) as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# Opening output file in append mode
# Note: Output file is not JSON, as the required format is not valid json
with open(output_file, "a+") as op:
    for element in data.get('X'):
        op.write(json.dumps(element) + "\n")
```

**Explanation:**

Load the input json file using `json.loads`. The output file will be a plain text file and not a JSON file as the required output format is not a valid JSON. Use a `.txt` file for storing the output. Store value of `json.loads()` in **data**. To get inner element **X** which is a list of dictionaries, use `data.get('X')`, which will return list. Iterate over it and write `json.dumps()` to the output file, each element in a newline.

**C:\XXX\exportReport.json**

```
{

    "X": [
       {
           "sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_1",
           ...
       }
       {
           "sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_2",
           ...
       }
       ......
     ]
     "Y": [
       {
           "sample_topic_y":"sample_content_y_1",
           ...
       }
       {
           "sample_topic_y":"sample_content_y_2",
           ...
       }
       ......
     ]
}
```

**C:\XXX\your_output_file.txt**

```
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_1",.....}
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_2",.....}
{"sample_topic_x":"sample_content_x_3",.....}
```

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Yes it does )), Solution works, but do you know any documentation with samples which will explain this kind of manipulation with JSON?

Comment: Dictionary manipulation in python:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: Thank you for your time and help.