# What is the correct way of editing a specific value in a json file?

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed

I have a file called `usr.json`, and this file contains a JSON object. The object looks as following:

```
{
  "users": {
          "accessRights":"FFFFF",
          "name": "admin"
         }
}
```

Now I want to replace the string for `accessRights` with a new value which is stored in a variable called `newUsrCfg`.

Since I'm working with a remote device I need to `ssh` to it, and for that I have a script.

However, I call all this in Python code:

```
def test_tc():
  newUsrCfg = "F7FFF"

  cmd = f'sed -ie \'s/\"accessRights\":.*/\"accessRights\": \"{newUsrCfg}\"/g\' "/etc/hgp/runtime/user/user1.json"'
  
  subprocess.call(["bash", pathToSshCommand, cmd])
```

The commands need to be either called with single quotes or double ones. And when opening the file the output of this is:

```
 {
      "users":{
               "accessRights": "f7fff"
```

I tried many other `sed` commands with different formats, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

If `jq` is available to you, you can

```
jq '.users.accessRights = "f7fff"' usr.json
```

As also commented below, manipulating `json` with text replacement is likely to break if your input does not exactly meet your expectations (for instance though differences in whitespace). If you have a tool like `jq` which understands `json`, that is always the preferable option.

However, in case you still want to do it with `sed` you could adjust your regex to be less inclusive. Since you want to replace 5 hex values, something along the following lines should work (I hope I escaped everything correctly, can't test since I'm on the way).

```
cmd = 'sed -ie \'s/\"accessRights\":\s*\"[0-9,a-f,A-F]\{5\}\"/\"accessRights\": \"{newUsrCfg}\"/g\' "/etc/hgp/runtime/user/user1.json"'
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sy9ubO/1).

A third option would to both [load the file via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597750/14015737) and [manipulate the json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949837/14015737) in Python, or do it directly in Python on the target system, if Python is available there as well.

Comment: Unfortunately,  jq is not available

Comment: @moab - It is available for most modern platforms.  See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ for a list ... though you wouldn't necessarily install it from there.   And using a tool like `jq` is vastly superior to using hacky "edit as text" approaches that are liable to break when they encounter unexpected input files.

Comment: @moab, our duplicates also cover doing this with Python, which is available effectively everywhere.