# json.dump adding another master object to the json file | discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am storing the points of every user on a Discord server in a `.json` file. When a user deserves an extra point, the following code in run and their point increments in the `.json` file.

```
user_id = msg.author.id
user_name = msg.author.display_name
with open("firework_economy.json", 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    if str(user_id) in data:
        print("Account already made")                       
        
        data[str(user_id)]["Fireworks"] += 1
        json.dump(data, f) 
    else:                              
        #data[str(user_id)] = {}
        data[str(user_id)]["Fireworks"] = 1
        json.dump(data, f)          
        await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention} earned 1 firework!")
```

I am expecting that the .json files changes from:

```
{
    "766571696491986965": {
        "Fireworks": 5}
}
```

to:

```
{
    "766571696491986965": {
        "Fireworks": 6}
}
```

But I am getting:

```
{
    "766571696491986965": {
        "Fireworks": 5}
}{"766571696491986965": {"Fireworks": 6}}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949637/how-to-update-json-file-with-python

Comment: The above comment is indeed the correct solution to this. I'd just like to add that you should consider using an actual database instead of a JSON file.

Comment: Thankyou both. In terms of the database, would it take more storage/ram/cpu on a local server as the host for my discord bot's resources is quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read fully the contents of a file, the file pointer gets to the end of the file. Hence when you are writing to it, you are writing at the end of the file.

Using `f.seek(0, 0)` before your `json.dump(...)` fixes your problem.